# Will Theme Gem + Ruby work on Windows PC to connect to Shopify?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, shopify

I want to sync my local theme files with my Shopify account. However, I want to make sure this is possible with Windows. I am sure it is, but just wanted to double check.

[REFERENCE:](https://docs.shopify.com/themes/theme-development/getting-started/choosing-an-editor)

Comment: Removed "...would be appreciated."  We generally leave out such phrases here.  Don't worry, it's always understood that you would be thankful.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to edit you shopify theme locally EVEN on windows.Do your research on beanstalk (http://beanstalkapp.com/shopify) and it will explain how you can do it.

I didn't use beanstalk but used shopify_theme  (https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_theme) to set up my local build and it worked fine but I ran into few problems with SSL Certificate Validation Error and it can be quite a nuisance.

Regardless of which option you choose you can hook it up to github and carry out version control for you shopify build, which I highly recommend.

Answer (score -1):

You might be surprised to find out that it does NOT work. My thought is that it won't since the gem depends on guard and watcher code that is likely not supported by Windows.

That being said, if the gem installs and works, good on ya!

Comment: Well, on the README.md of the gem on [Github](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_theme#requirements), they explicitly state first-class Windows support. Also, the [filewatcher](https://github.com/thomasfl/filewatcher) gem which is a dependency if this gem polls the filesystem on its own and is completely platform-independent. Why do you assume the gem would not be compatible with Windows?

Comment: Thanks Holger.. You are right. according to: the reference link, it states windows is compatible here: 

Requirements

This gem works with OS X or Windows with Ruby 1.9.

First time installing Ruby on Windows? Try Rubyinstaller.

Comment: Well @Holger, mostly since those watch gems (fileguard whatever).. have often been borked even on *nix where they stand the best chance of working. And secondly, Windows supports only Ruby 1.9 for that which is kinda like saying use Windows 95... I guess it works first class... for 2005 type computing... so be it.

Comment: The gem is [tested](https://travis-ci.org/Shopify/shopify_theme) on Ruby 1.9.3 as well as 2.0, other gems also on newer Ruby versions. And given that the gem does very little on its own, there is little indication that it shouldn't work on newer Rubies too. So unless you have any *actual* evidence that the gem doesn't work on Windows and/or recent Ruby versions, please don't spread wrong information.

Comment: Well, when someone asks a wishy washy question they could answer for themselves by just doing it, they get an answer based on experience and best guesses. No one would be silly enough to say Windows certainly works with anything, unless of course they are naive and without any experience with it. I stand by my answer. It might work, but there is a probability it won't, for reasons no one knows.